# Android create simple volley Singleton class to prepare GET and POST method

Tags: android, android-volley

with android `Volley` tutorials i'm creating simple single Singleton class as an Volley, but after prepare GET and POST method i get `NullPointerException` error and i can not find whats error:

AppControllert `Volley` singleton class:

```
public class ApplicationController extends Application {
    public static final String TAG = "VolleyPatterns";
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private static ApplicationController sInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sInstance = this;
    }
    public static synchronized ApplicationController getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }
    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }
    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        VolleyLog.e("Adding request to queue: %s", req.getUrl());
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }
    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);

        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }
    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

and in Activity i'm try to create simple request with this class:

```
final String URL = "http://192.168.1.6/apitest";
JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.e("Response:", response.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
    }
});
ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
```

Logcat error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at asrebidaree.ir.asrebidaree.ActivityRegistration.onCreate(ActivityRegistration.java:37)
```

Line 37 is : `ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);`

Comment: What is the ActivityRegistration.java:37 line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code looks good. You have to register your Application's subclass in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. If you didn't, your `sInstance` will not be initialized, since Android will not use your Application's sublcass

Comment: thanks problem resolve. please let me to accept and vote up your answer.